Is it possible to generate a pickerInput with sub-choices in Shiny?
I'm wondering if it is possible to create a pickerInput, which allows to select items from a nested hierarchy (list()), like the one below in shiny.
(see comments, cant post the picture because I get the error "Your post mainly contains images")


Picture: https://i.sstatic.net/6qArfrBM.png

You could use library(NestedMenu).
Please find an example here:
library(NestedMenu)
library(shiny)

cities <- list(
  europe = list(
    name = "Europe",
    items = list(
      france = list(
        name = "France",
        icon = "fa-cheese",
        items = list(
          paris = list(name = "Paris"),
          lyon = list(name = "Lyon")
        )
      ),
      italy = list(
        name = "Italy",
        icon = "fa-pizza-slice",
        items = list(
          roma = list(name = "Roma"),
          milano = list(name = "Milano")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  america = list(
    name = "America",
    items = list(
      namerica = list(
        name = "North America",
        items = list(
          usa = list(
            name = "USA",
           icon = "fa-flag-usa",
            items = list(
              chicago = list(name = "Chicago"),
              newyork = list(name = "New York")
            )
          ),
          canada = list(
            name = "Canada",
            icon = "fa-canadian-maple-leaf",
            items = list(
              ottawa = list(name = "Ottawa"),
              toronto = list(name = "Toronto")
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      samerica = list(
        name = "South America",
        items = list(
          brazil = list(
            name = "Brazil",
            icon = "fa-lemon",
            items = list(
              brasilia = list(name = "Brasilia"),
              saopolo = list(name = "Sao Polo")
            )
          ),
          mexico = list(
            name = "Mexico",
            icon = "fa-hat-cowboy",
            items = list(
              mexicocity = list(name = "Mexico City"),
              tijuana = list(name = "Tijuana")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  NestedMenuOutput("menu", height = "auto"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("clicked")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["menu"]] <- renderNestedMenu({
    NestedMenu(
      "Cities", items = cities
    )
  })

  output[["clicked"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["menu"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Do you know if it is possible to have all levels of the picked value returned? For example, if I choose Paris it would return besides Paris also France and Europe?

It seems this currently isn't implemented. All you get is the clicked leaf. You might want to try posting a feature request here asking to implement another input, which provides the selected path. However, you might be able to create a workaround, as those
items all have the css class context-menu-hover assigned.
